# Opencart 4 Extension Route throws 404

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

I'm trying to develop an Opencart4 Extension and for some reason it's throwing a 404 when I try to access it.

I've the following structure:

/opencart/extensions/myextension/admin/controller/payment/myextension.php
/opencart/extensions/myextension/admin/template/payment/myextension.twig

and here's the controller:

```php
<?PHP

namespace Opencart\Admin\Controller\Extension\MyExtension\Payment;

class MyExtension extends \Opencart\System\Engine\Controller {

   public function index() {

        $data = array();

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/myextension/payment/myextension', $data));
   }
}
```

Now when I try to access the http://localhost/admin123/index.php?route=extension/myextension/payment/myextension, I get a 404 page!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

template must be twig file:

```
/opencart/extensions/myextension/admin/template/payment/myextension.twig
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo, it's a twig file only

Answer (score 0):

that works extension in opencart 4, before need compile your extension to

myextension.ocmod.zip

and then install from admin, then should works.

this is correct structure.

[image]